# Android Lips Synch on playing audio

Tags: image-processing, android-animation, android-audiorecord

1. I have to attach duplicate lips to image.
2. When audio is playing at that time duplicate lips which we have    attached  to image  lips will do movement.

Comment: Please see ["How to ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sections...

Comment: thanks i will go through it